# Does reflection require a self-concept or self knowledge?

Tags: consciousness

We reflect on what is within us and outside us. However it is not clear whether the power of reflection which is unique to humans (which I guess so) requires a concept of Self or Self knowledge?

So my question is : Does reflection require a self concept or self knowledge?Also , how can we know whether animals reflect or not ? Is it possible to create an experiment to know whether animals reflect or not ?

Comment: Please give us first your definition of "Self".

Comment: @JoWehler good question. Self means the “I” when I say I eat food or I like vegetarian food … etc

Comment: IMO the question becomes much more easy when replacing "Self" by "I" or "me" or "myself" or "mine". - Nevertheless, I consider it a difficult task to achieve a psychological model of the first-person stance; e.g. from the viewpoint of philosopy and neuroscience see "Thomas Metzinger: Being No One".

Comment: For instance, some have argued that the experiments done to test whether animals are capable of metacognition (or thinking about their thoughts) can in fact be passed by reasoning solely in first-order terms (or thinking about the world). Since first-order thinking is assumed to be a simpler explanation of the data, it has been argued that this explanation ought to be favored (e.g., Carruthers 2003; Hampton 2009). https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/cognition-animal/

Comment: @prof_ghost thanks for the link. I have also seen animals behaving intelligently.. but do they reflect ?